# Calculate additional value in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I need to write a java method to calculate an additional value.

I have a candy bar that costs $10 (`price`). I need to calculate an added value of 20% (`ADDED_VALUE`) so I do the following:

```
price + price*ADDED_VALUE or 10 + 10*20%
```

and I get `12`. But now I need to calculate 10% (`NEW_ADD_VALUE`) on this `12`, but I don't know how to do it.

What I've tried so far:

```
double priceWithAddedValue() {

    return price + price * ADDED_VALUE + price * NEW_ADDED_VALUE
}
```

However the above code returns `13` and I'm suppose to get `13.2`.

Comment: Is `ADDED_VALUE` or `NEW_ADDED_VALUE` or `price` a double? Perhaps worth posting some more code.

Comment: @CollinD it looks like `price` is an `int`, `ADDED_VALUE` is hopefully a `double` and `NEW_ADDED_VALUE` is a `double`. This is an assumption however, they could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should refactor this into a general method which takes an initial double and a fraction indicating what should be added:

```
double addFraction(double initialValue, double fraction) {
    return initialValue + fraction*initialValue;
}
```

After this, it is very easy to do this twice:

```
addFraction(addFraction(10, 0.2), 0.1);
```

You could of course split this into multiple statements.

So this would look like this in your example:

```
double priceWithAddedValue(){
    return addFraction(addFraction(price, ADDED_VALUE), NEW_ADDED_VALUE);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Leonard http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing you need to focus on is order of operations, especially the function of the parenthesis, since not only is it valuable knowledge to posses for programming but also for day to day life. (if you use math in your day to day life)

What your trying to do is multiply a number, by the addition of, the product of two numbers.

```
double priceWithAddedValue() {

    return (price + price * ADDED_VALUE) * NEW_ADDED_VALUE;
}
```

Next you should focus on variable types, like `float`, `int`, `double`, `char`. The problem you're facing with getting `3` instead of `3.2` is due to `int` only representing integers (`. , -2, -1, 0 , 1 , 2 , .`). be fine using a `double`

Comment: Ah, I flagged this before the grace period edit. The first version was more of a comment, but after the edit I regret having flagged so soon.

Comment: @11684 I honestly wouldn't mind if this got deleted, the first accepted answer was wrong with a score of -1.

Comment: I think that, as it stands, this is probably the best answer. It's the only one that adresses the actual issues at play here.

Comment: @11684 thanks for the "sorry I flagged your answer" up-vote : ) You've inspired me to finish it

Comment: @Leonard I abandoned this answer half way through writing it, but I've decided (for completeness) to finish it. Allow me some time to finish, and I'll try to thoroughly explain everything understandably, and address some assumptions of where you might be having trouble.

Comment: @Jonny Henly Thank you, I'll admit mathematics is not my strong side but I know what is older mathematical operation and about braces, I also tried what you have write but it did not work. Also I'm new in trying to learn Java.